Are dtype names case-insensitive?
I am following this guide on working with text data types.  From there, I cobbled the following:
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan], dtype="Int64")
s1

   0       1
   1       2
   2    <NA>
   dtype: Int64

type(s1[0])

   numpy.int64

I noticed that the int64 has inconsistent case in the two lines of output.  Why is this?
